# python docker client does not execute mysql command in a right way

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, docker, dockerpy

I'm using [MySQL docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) and a docker python client in such a code

```
import docker

client = docker.from_env()
container_name = 'local-mysql'

path_to_current_dir = '/home/user/workspace'

container = client.containers.run(
    'mysql',
    name=container_name,
    auto_remove=True,
    environment={
        'MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD': True,
    },
    detach=True,
    volumes={
        path_to_current_dir: {'bind': '/data/', 'mode': 'ro'},
    }
)

er = container.exec_run('mysql -h localhost < /data/init.sql')
```

Basically I just want to execute mounted `*.sql` file within a container but receive nothing than `mysql --help` output in `er.output` and exit code is `1`. Running with `docker exec -it local-mysql bash` and manually executing `mysql -h localhost < /data/init.sql` works perfectly. Providing `tty=True` parameter doesn't help too.

This is content of my `init.sql` file

```
CREATE DATABASE my_test;


CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `text` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I suspect something wrong with my command (formed not in the way docker client accepts?). This is my env for more details:
`Python 2.7.12`, `Docker version 17.12.1-ce, build 7390fc6`, client `docker==3.1.1`, mysql within container `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.21, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`.

What might be wrong here?

Comment: THANK YOU for posting this question. I've been hunting for clues to a solution for the exact same problem and yours is the first one I've found that is EXACTLY the same problem as mine. The accepted answer worked a treat for me too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are on host and want to feed some script with `<`, use pipe `|` or just multiple commands with `&&` you have to do it with this bash trick `/bin/bash -c "some command` so it will pass the whole command as a whole to the container.

```
docker exec -it local-mysql /bin/bash -c "mysql -h localhost < /data/init.sql"
```

Comment: You sir, are THE MAN! I can't tell you how much this issue has been frustrating me tonight. Ploughed through loads of google searches to no avail and stumbled across this question and your answer. THANK YOU!